# Integral of $1/x$

Tags: calculus, integration

Why is the integral of $1/x$ only equal to $\ln|x| + C$ when I remember seeing that

$$\frac d{dx}(\ln Cx) = \frac1{Cx} \cdot C = \frac 1x$$

Shouldn't $\int \frac1x \, dx$ be something like $\ln|C_1x| +C_2$?

Comment: $\ln |x| + C$ *is* something like $\ln|C_1x| + C_2= \ln|x| + \ln|C_1| + C_2$.  Just set $C = \ln|C_1| + C_2$ and they are the exact same things.

Comment: They are the same thing if you apply the laws of logs

Comment: Expressing it as $\ln|Cx|$ is an equivalent alternative to writing $\ln|x| + c$ by laws of logs but since the former applies only to the logarithmic function and the latter is universally applicable to all indefinite integrals, we go with the latter for consistency. But you can certainly express your answers more compactly using the former expression.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

\begin{align}
& \ln\left|C_1 x\right| + C_2 \\[10pt]
={} & \ln \left|x\right| + \ln \left|C_1\right| + C_2 \\[10pt]
= {} & \ln \left|x\right| + \text{constant}
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
log(mn)=log(m)+log(n)

....